# Sandboxing with javax.script

Tags: java

I'd like to add scripting functionality to an app that runs in a Java EE container. The javax.script API seems ideal, since I can support multiple languages with one API; the catch is, the scripts may be coming from untrusted sources, so I need to restrict what they can do. Basically, here are my requirements:

1. Multiple scripts running at the same time.
2. The scripts do not interact with each other.
3. The scripts have no access to the JVM or the Java application code.
4. The scripts have no access to the underlying platform (file system, etc).
5. The scripts have no network access.

If I can allow specific exceptions, that's great, but it's not essential.

Can this be done at all through the Java Scripting API? Can it be done at a lower level by configuring the scripting providers? Is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: You are going to have difficulty removing "access to the JVM [and] the application code".

Comment: Another thing to think about is not letting scripts hog the CPU - that might be a hard one to restrict.

Comment: @Jesper: if I can decrease the script-executing thread's priority, AND prevent the script from spawning threads, I should be able to limit the damage. In this case, I could also track how long each script takes to run, and block any that are excessively slow. I think a bigger problem will be preventing memory hogging.